# Taking data passed like attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I did a directive to call related posts of a blog portal. It should work by passing the labels of the reading post like an attribute called "labels". But when I try to do it, the directive returns the literal content instead the variable value.

```
<!-- Here works fine -->
<related-posts labels="post.labels"> {{ labels }} </related-posts>

// Here my issue
app.directive('relatedPosts', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/related-posts.html',
        scope: {
            labels: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            console.log($attrs['labels']); // returns "post.labels" instead "Label 1, Label 2, etc..."
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please access the variable like this.

**Explanation:** You have setup the scope properly but you are using `$attrs.labels` which will just access the label value as a text, hence you get `post.labels`, since you bound it to the scope, you need to access it like `$scope.labels`

<kbd>**`JSFiddle`**</kbd>

```
<!-- Here works fine -->
<related-posts labels="post.labels"> {{ labels }} </related-posts>

// Here my issue
app.directive('relatedPosts', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/related-posts.html',
        scope: {
            labels: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            console.log($scope.labels); 
        }
    }
});
```